# minimize number of $watch calls of an ng-show inside of an ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, performance, watch, ng-show

What is the best way to use ng-show only for items that has a valid function show()?

For example:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in ::settingsMenuList | orderBy:'index'" ng-show="{{item.show ? 'item.show()' : 'true'}}">
    <a ng-bind="item.text" ng-click="item.click($event)"></a>
</li>
```

Is there any other performance best practice here?

Thanks!

Comment: One thing you may want to consider is reduce the list to iterate in ng-repeat, by combining with a filter... just a hunch

Comment: just do `ng-show="{{item.show && item.show()}}` to answer the question

Comment: This is not directly related to your question, but FYI, the AngularJS docs recommend against mixing `ng-repeat` with other directives on the same element (https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq#combining-ng-repeat-with-other-directives) (i.e., the other directives should go on an element inside one with `ng-repeat`).

Comment: efficiency wise is more efficient to filter the collection before passing it to the markup

Comment: @Dinesh & @charlietfi, do you mean I should use `scope.settingsMenuList = $filter('orderBy')(scope.settingsMenuList, 'index');` instead of the filter in the ng-repeat?
@JLRishe, thanks, did not know that.
@Mathew, it will make items without a show function to be hidden.